# If $\lambda$ is an eignevalue of $B$,then choose the correct option

Tags: linear-algebra

let $A$  be  any  $n\times n$ non singular complex  matrix  and let $B = (\bar A)^tA,$ where $(\bar A)^t$ is the conjugate  transpose  of $A$. If  $\lambda$ is  an eignevalue  of $B$,then

choose the correct option

$a)$$\lambda$ is real and  $\lambda  < 0$

$b)$$\lambda$ is real and  $\lambda  \le 0$

$c)$$\lambda$ is real and  $\lambda  > 0$

$d)$$\lambda$ is real and  $\lambda  \ge 0$

I thinks   option  $d)$  will correct

Is  it  True ??

Comment: For this kind of exercises, you can take a rather good hint from assuming stuff on $\;A\;$ . For example, what if this matrix , and thus also $\;B\;$ , is singular? Then it could perfectly well be that $\;\lambda=0\;$ ...Can you see how the number of options gets smaller?

Comment: @DonAntonio  thanks u...i missed that